# Integrando o PayPal ExpressCheckout em PHP

Tags: php, api

desde já algum tempo que tenho pesquisado como integrar o PayPal em minhas lojas online, as que eu mesmo construo do 0 até a etapa final que é o pagamento, mas quando fui ao site do PayPal para saber mais acerca da integração deparei-me com alguns problemas, que era interpretar o NVP (Name-Pair-Value), de modo a conectar com a API do PayPal e definir os métodos ou requisições para iniciar até completar a compra, mas depois uma série de pesquisas e estudos de scripts OpenSource, apesar de parecerem complexos consegui entende-los ao todo, e consegui também integrar o PayPal ExpressCheckout as minhas a minha loja.

As principais perguntas são:

Como conecto com a API do PayPal sem comprometer as minhas credenciais ?

Como defino os métodos necessários para o ExpressCheckout ?

Como sei que a compra foi efectuada ou concluída sem erros ?

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida? Seja mais específico por favor.

Comment: @Deyel - A minha dúvida, é mesmo sobre a implementação duma API que me permita terminar as vendas, porque nos meus scripts ou lojas paro sempre nessa fase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ExpressCheckout é utilizado para realizar comprar/vendas seguras no site do PayPal e no fim da compra o cliente retorna ao site do usuário ou empresa.

Para entender como funciona o ExpressCheckout do PayPal, tem antes que perceber o seu fluxo de funcionamento.

Loja -> Pedido (SetExpressCheckout) -> Servidor Responde Com Token -> Redirecionamento HTTP com &token= -> ->URL de Retorno + TOKEN -> Pedido (GetExpressCheckoutDetails) -> Resposta -> Pedido (DoExpressCheckoutPayment) -> Resposta (Success/Failure) -> Ordem  Completa

Conectando com a API do PayPal.

```
     <?php
     class paypal{
//Função de conexão com a API
function api($comando,$param){
    $api = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp'; # URL para o modo sandbox
    $api_user = urlencode('<API_USUARIO>');
    $api_senha = urlencode('<API_SENHA>');
    $api_assinatura = urlencode('<API_ASSINATURA>');
    $api_versao = urlencode('109.0'); # Esta é a versão da API a ser utilizada
    $i = curl_init();
    # Definimos uma cabeçalho para a requisição
    curl_setopt($i, CURLOPT_URL, $api); 
    curl_setopt($i, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    #Desactivar a verificação do servidor e do peer
    curl_setopt($i, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($i, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($i, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($i, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //Passando os parâmetros da API
    $nvp = "METHOD=$comando&VERSION=$api_versao&PWD=$api_senha&USER=$api_user&SIGNATURE=$api_assinatura$param";

    //Definindo o nvp como campo POST do cURL
    curl_setopt($i, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp);
    $resposta = curl_exec($i);
    curl_close($i);

    if(!$resposta){
        exit("Erro do $comando ".curl_error($i)."(".curl_errno($i).")");
        }
    #Aqui transformamos a nossa URL numa array associativa
    $respostaP = $this->nvp($resposta);
    if(0 == sizeof($respostaP) || !array_key_exists('ACK',$respostaP)){
        exit("HTTP resposta inválida do servidor($nvp) para $api");
        }

    return $respostaP;
    }
    // função para converter a resposta da cURL em array
    function nvp($resposta){
    $i = explode('&',$resposta);
    $respostaP = array();
    foreach($i as $key=>$value){
    $d = explode('=',$value);
    if(sizeof($d)>1){
    $respostaP[$d[0]] = $d[1];
     }
    }
    return $respostaP;
    }


}
```

?>

Depois de definir as variáveis de conexão, pode-se então definir os métodos a serem da chamada para iniciar e completar a compra.

```
    <?php

    //Iniciamos a sessão
    session_start();

   //Incluimos a nossa classe 
   include_once('paypal.php');

   //Se for utilizar o modo live, deixe a variavel $paypalmodo com o ponto(.) apenas
   $paypalmodo = '.sandbox';
   $moeda = 'USD';
   $urlRetorno = 'http://site.com/retorno';
   $urlCancela = 'http://site.com/cancela';

   //Parte que trata do SetExpressCheckout
   if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){

$itemNome = $_POST['itemNome'];
$itemPreco = $_POST['itemPreco'];
$itemQnt = $_POST['itemQnt'];
$itemTotal = ($itemPreco*$itemQnt);

$taxa = 1.50;

$total = ($itemTotal + $taxa);

$nvpData = '&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout'.
           '&RETURNURL='.urlencode($urlRetorno).
           '&CANCELURL='.urlencode($urlCancela).
           '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode('Sale').
           '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0='.urlencode($itemNome).

           '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0='.urlencode($itemTotal).
           '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0='.urlencode($itemQnt).

           '&NOSHIPPING=0'.

           '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($itemTotal).
           '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT='.urlencode($taxa).
           '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($total).
           '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($moeda).

           '&LOCALECODE=BR'.
           '&LOGOIMG='.'http://site.com/logo_a_utilizar_caso_tenha.jpg'.
           '&CARTBORDERCOLOR=45D765'.
           '&ALLOWNOTE=1';

//Definindo as as variaveis de SESSAO
$_SESSION['itemNome'] = $itemNome;
$_SESSION['itemPreco'] = $itemPreco;
$_SESSION['itemQnt'] = $itemQnt;
$_SESSION['itemTotal'] = $itemTotal;

$_SESSION['taxa'] = $taxa;
$_SESSION['total'] = $total;


//Instanciado a class paypal e chamando a função  de conexão api('SetExpressCheckout','paramentros_da_url') 
$paypal = new paypal();
$resposta = $paypal->api('SetExpressCheckout',$nvpData);

if('SUCCESS' == strtoupper($resposta['ACK']) || 'SUCCESSWITHWARNING' == strtoupper($resposta['ACK'])){
    //Url de redirectionamento com os parâmetros inseridos
    $paypalUrl = 'https://www'.$paypalmodo.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$resposta["TOKEN"].'';
    header('Location:'.$paypalUrl);
    } else {
        echo '<div style="color:red"><b>Erro : </b>'.urldecode($resposta["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
        }
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($resposta);
    echo '</pre>';

}

    //Parte que trata do DoExpressCheckout

    if(isset($_GET['token']) && isset($_GET['PayerID'])){

$token = $_GET['token'];
$payer_id = $_GET['PayerID'];

$itemNome = $_SESSION['itemNome'];
$itemNum = $_SESSION['itemNum'];
$itemQnt = $_SESSION['itemQnt'];
$itemTotal = $_SESSION['itemTotal'];

$taxa = $_SESSION['taxa'];
$total = $_SESSION['total'];

$nvpData = '&TOKEN='.urlencode($token).
           '&PAYERID='.urlencode($payer_id).
           '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode("Sale").

           '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0='.urlencode($itemNome).
           '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0='.urlencode($itemPreco).
           '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0='.urlencode($itemQnt).

           '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($itemTotal).
           '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT='.urlencode($taxa).
           '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($total).
           '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($moeda);


//Instanciando a class paypal e chamando a função api('DoExpressCheckoutPayment','paramentros_da_url')         
$paypal = new paypal();
$resposta = $paypal->api('DoExpressCheckoutPayment',$nvpData);

if('SUCCESS' == strtoupper($resposta['ACK']) || 'SUCCESSWITHWARNING' == strtoupper($resposta['ACK'])){

    echo "<h2 style='color:green;'>Concluído</h2>";
    echo "ID da sua compra: ".$resposta['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID'];

    if('Completed' == $resposta['PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS']){
        session_destroy();
        echo '<div style="color:green">Pagamento completo! Obrigado pela compra.</div>';
        } else if('Peding' == $resposta['PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS']){
            echo '<div style="color:red">Transação completa, mas o pagamento precisa de ser aprovado manualmente na sua <a target="_new" href="http://www.paypal.com">Conta do PayPal</a></div>';
            }

    //Parte Responsavel por pegar os detalhes da transação
    //Esta parte só é exibida se a transação for efectuada com sucesso ou retornar Success
    $nvpData = '&TOKEN='.urlencode($token);
    $paypal = new paypal();
    $resposta = $paypal->api('GetExpressCheckoutDetails',$nvpData);

if('SUCCESS' == strtoupper($resposta['ACK']) || 'SUCCESSWITHWARNING' == strtoupper($resposta['ACK'])){


                echo '<br /><b>Coisas para adicionar no banco de dados :</b><br /><pre>';

                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($resposta);
                echo '</pre>';
            } else  {
                echo '<div style="color:red"><b>GetTransactionDetails failed:</b>'.urldecode($resposta["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r(urldecode($resposta));
                echo '</pre>';


        }

    } else {
        //Esta parte é responsavel por verificar o erro caso a chamada api('DoExpressCheckoutPayment','paramentros') falhe.
        echo "Erro :".urldecode($resposta['L_LONGMESSAGE0']);
        echo "<pre>";
        foreach($resposta as $id=>$valor){
            echo "<div style='color:red; border:2px solid #ccc;'>[".$id."] => ".urldecode($valor)."<br/></div>";
            }
        echo "</pre>";
        }



}
    ?>
```

E finalmente a página responsável por fornecer os dados acerca do item pelo método POST.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Site.com(LOJA)</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {background-color:#D7D7D7;}
    *{font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;}
    h1 {text-align:center; color:#333; font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
    h4 {color:#333; font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
    table {border:1px solid #666; border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px; box-shadow:1px 0px 1px #999 inset; background-color:#F2F2F2; margin:0 auto;}
    input {border:1px solid #333; border-radius:4px 5px 5px 5px; box-shadow:1px 0px 1px #999 inset; padding:5px; margin-top:2px;}
    input:hover {background-color:#FFF; transition:ease-in-out 0.4s; box-shadow:1px 0px 1px #CCC inset;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    $moeda = 'USD';
    ?>
    <h1>Site.com</h1>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
    <td width="70%"><h4>Bilhetes Platina</h4>(Se vai ao concerto logo a noite, esta é a  sua melhor chance de ficar na fila V.I.P)</td>
    <td width="30%">
    <form method="post" action="checkout.php">
<input type="hidden" name="itemNome" value="Bilhetes Platina" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="itemPreco" value="20.00" />
    Quantidade : <select name="itemQnt"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select> 
    <input type="submit"  value="Comprar (20.00 <?php echo $moeda; ?>)" />
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Uma dúvida: parece que nesse seu exemplo o carrinho só pode ter apenas  1 produto. E no caso de uma loja onde os clientes compram vários produtos no mesmo pedido? O que fazer?

Comment: E no caso de ter frete, qual o nome do parâmetro sendo que os fretes de todos os itens do carrinho são somados em 1 só

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que explicar todas as etapas de criação de uma API (Application Program Interface) não é viável.

Se você está afim de gastar uma grana para aprender, existem alguns cursos como este: [Curso Criação e Utilização de APIs em PHP](http://bravacursos.com.br/curso-desenvolvimento-utilizacao-api-php/).

Caso contrário, recomendo assistir vídeo aulas do YouTube como essa: [PHP Tutorial: Developer API [part 00]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdGwOSOIp4A).

Na medida que as dúvidas surgirem, você pode perguntar aqui no StackOverflow.

Comment: acho que ele quer usar a API do paypal, não fazer uma própria (se bem que a pergunta não está clara pra mim).

Comment: Já aprendi a usar a API, obrigado pela tentativa.